# Android registerOnSharedPreferenceChangelistener only triggered a few times after that not working

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

Hello so I have the problem that I registered a onSharedPreferenceChangeListener in my MainActivity. The only preference I have is a ListPreference with 3 different options. So at the start of the program it still gets triggered the first - 3 times mostly, sometimes it doesn't even trigger at the beginning. I don't think that's how it is supposed to work so my code is down below if more is needed just write a comment of a specific part.

```
// (from MainActivity)
this.sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences, s: String ->
    var value = sharedPreferences.getString("location", "")

    controller.setLocation(value, this)
}



class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity)
        supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings, SettingsFragment())
                .commit()
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)


    }

    class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: https://github.com/Pixplicity/EasyPrefs try using this library for prefrences might help

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by myself, for everyone who is having an issue like that. It's probably the scope. The listener gets lost when you are switching between activities. 
How to fix: put the listener block as a global variable and just register it in your "onCreate" method.